# Android abort uninstalling app for user 0

Tags: android

I execute command for system app

```
pm uninstall -k --user 0 name.of.package
```

How I can cancel it? Something like pm install -k --user 0 name.of.package... 
Can't find correct command to abort uninstalling.

Thanks